# Converting a double list into a string

Tags: c#, ajax, arrays, json, list

I have an array of double which I am sending via JSON to my aspx page.

```
var array = [] //this array is having double values in it. (48.154176701412744,11.551694869995117),(48.15131361676726,11.551694869995117),(48.15555092529958,11.549291610717773)

var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: array });
```

And following is the method I am passing it to:

```
public static void Demo(double[] list)
```

Now how can I access the array being sent and convert it into a string so that I can save it into my database column as string? Because when I accept it as

```
public static void Demo(string[] list)
```

It doesn't even accept the JSON object. And when I  make the method as:

```
public static void Demo(double[] list)
```

It takes the array as [0 0 0].

Answer (score 0):

You can join all doubles with some delimiter:

```
 string.Join(";", list);
```

However, you should pay attention to using decimal separator. If value will be saved as `1.52;0.4`, later you can fail on another machine, or if locale will be changed. I'd decide, what separator I will use always for this case and will convert values to string and back with this separator:

```
 // unfortunately, not tested
 var ni = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo; // not sure if you better call Clone() here
 ni.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
 string todatabase = string.Join(";", list.Select(_ => _.ToString(ni)));
```

To do the opposite operation:

```
 // unfortunately, not tested
 var ni = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo; // not sure if you better call Clone() here
 ni.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
 // `str` is read from database value
 IEnumerable<double> fromdatabase = str.Split(';').Select(_ => double.Parse(_, ni));
```

Pay attention to errors handling, this code fragments will fail on bad values (e.g. list was null, str was null, str was containing not-convertible to double values, etc)

Comment: I have updated my question, now you can understand what my exact problem is.

Comment: Oh, so, I'm not helper, don't know anything about JSON -_- But you sure array is doubles array? I see array of double *pairs* (points, maybe?)

Comment: Nope! it is having strings in it but it when I send it to method it fails at string but it at least accepts JSON object when its double. Thats weird and confusing me.

Comment: @mazharrenko Can you identify what the exact data type of this array? If yes, then kindly tell me as this will make things very easy.

Comment: @ejazdogar it's still unclear for me. You can get know it just pointing your cursor on the `var` keyword. Also breakpoints always help )

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringfy is itself return a string then why do you need to convert the values to string.You can use  JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(jsonText)') to parse the json string on aspx page.This json string can be passed using Session variable.